# iPhone full screen advertisement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iad

I am developing an iPhone app and according to my business plan, I need my application to support full screen advertisements. I have checked WWDC, Apple Docs and found that `ADInterstitialAd` which offers what I am after is only supported on the iPad. So, I am asking about any workarounds or alternatives to display full screen ads in my application.

Any suggestion is very welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for iAd solutions only?

Comment: @MarcusAdams It's ok if there is a third-party solution. I don't mind using a non-apple framework!

Comment: It is now possible since iOS 7.0. Answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741622/iads-interstitial-adverts-on-iphone/20858735#20858735

Answer (score 7):

You can show full screen ads by using the SDKs from some of the mobile big ad companies.

1) These are free to download and install, 
2) They take about 15 mins to integrate into your app in xCode. 
3) They all have instructions on their websites you can follow to set them up 
4) You can usually set when and where you can these full screen ads to appear in your app quite easily
5) These work on iPad / iPhone / iPodtouch.

COMPANIES:

[www.revmob.com](http://www.revmob.com) - full screens, banners, popups. Your app will show ads for big iOS games (candy crush etc) and if a user clicks on them you will get paid from revmob.

[www.playhaven.com](http://www.playhaven.com) - full screens, more screens and other interesting options. Your app will show ads for big iOS games (candy crush etc) and if a user clicks on them you will get paid from revmob.

[www.chartboost.com](http://www.chartboost.com) - As well as doing what the two companies above do, you can also show full screen ads for ANYTHING - you can make up your own artwork and cross promote to your other games.

Hope that helps. 
Elaine
[www.thechocolatelabapps.com](http://www.thechocolatelabapps.com)

Answer (score 6):

Other ad networks (Millennial Media, AdMob, etc.) offer full screen interstitial ads for smaller devices.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Flexicoder OP was asking for a way to work around the fact that iAd didn't offer full screen interstitials for small devices. I pointed out that other ad networks *do* provide such ads, the obvious conclusion being that the OP could switch to a different ad network if he/she wanted full screen ads. Why do you think that's not an answer, and why do you think I was critiquing the question or asking for clarification? Note that the two other answers, both of which also have a positive vote total, provide essentially the same suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at AdMob Interstitials Ads, which provide full screen ads for small devices:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

Answer (score 1):

The variety of networks that offer interstitial ads is rather big, just a few of most popular: AdMob, Amazon Ads, Applovin, Chartboost, Facebook ads, Tapsense, MoPub, Appnexus and many others. AdMob is quite reliable, i use it through Appodeal plugin for Chrome, this helps to increase the perfomance. At the same time i got access to Chartboost, Applovin, Mopub, Facebook and other networks via Appodeal account. There you can adjust different settings in your dashboard, I suppose it's the easiest way to show different types of ads on all supported devices.