# iAd: Is it possible to occasionally make a full screen ad out of the banner?

Tags: ios, iad

I wasn't able to find anything or good enough information about this. Is it possible to create a full screen ad randomly out of the banner?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iAd Overview](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/Implementing-iAd-in-Your-iOS-Apps.PDF) the thing you're looking for is called [`ADInterstitialAd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/ADInterstitialAd_Ref/index.html), <del>but it seems like it's iPad only</del>.

> The ADInterstitialAd class provides full-screen advertisements that your iPad application can display to the user. [...]

Anyway, have a look at the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple and run it against a simulator.

**Edit:** As Daniel Storm mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741622/iads-interstitial-adverts-on-iphone/20858735#20858735) it ***is*** supported on iPhone as well, but has a low fill rate.

Comment: iAd interstitials are available on iPhone starting at iOS 7.0. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741622/iads-interstitial-adverts-on-iphone/20858735#20858735

Comment: So the PDF is outdated… great

Comment: The PDF doesn't seem out of date. It does mention the use of interstitials and shows a mockup on an iPhone sized screen. The sample project seems to need updating although.. The issue is when Apple released interstitials for iPhone at the launch of iOS 7 it seemed like they didn't want anyone to know as they went about hiding the new features under "UIViewController iAd Additions Reference" rather than right under the "ADInterstitialAd" class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013388

Comment: Oh damn… I meant the reference not the PDF.