# How to integrate iAd Interstitial Ads with Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad

I have a fully functioning game built in Cocos2D and I want to add the iAd full-page Interstitial serving to it. I've googled for some time without much success - all I can find is tutorials on how to add banner iAds (constant serving, placed on top or below the game) but nothing about how to serve the Interstitials at key points of the game (like "Save Me" button to watch the ad or when game is over). Can anyone please help point me in the right direction or be kind enough to share how you did it on your app? Thanks!

Comment: Here's an answer concerning iAd's interstitial ads I posted awhile ago (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20858735/2108547). The code is quite dated now but the concept and links to Apple Doc's remain the same. Personally, I use AdMob for interstitials as they are extremely easy to implement compared to iAd.

Comment: @DanielStorm thanks for the share - will this work with Cocos though? I have found that integrating the view controller with cocos is beyond me!

Comment: @NatureFriend thanks for the link! am I missing something where it covers full page interstitials? it seems like this only covers banners and that's not my problem...