# Creating Fullscreen Ads using iAd and SpriteKit (iOS)

Tags: ios, fullscreen, iad

So Ive been trying to integrate iAd into my app. I managed to get banners working just fine but I have been having a lot of trouble with the fullscreen ads. I have been following [this tutorial](http://blog.lucaslouca.com/interstitial-ads-iphone-ios-7/) as it seems to be the best and most informative one that I found and the apple docs don't really off much support.

For those wanting to know, I am trying to achieve an effect where when the user gets a game over a fullscreen ad is displayed. bearing in mind ***the app is also horizontal*** and I would also like a way to exit the ad as I believe that the iAds don't come with an exit button, or something similar.

**The problem is that the ad isn't displayed, I'm not getting any errors it just doesnt seem to get shown on screen**

Apologize if the explanation is short or lacks information, ask away if you need anything else from me :)

-Ryan

***EDIT:
to those who can't access the hyperlink or simply want to see the code I'm using, here it is:***

```
@implementation GameViewController {
    UIView *_adView;
    ADInterstitialAd* _interstitial;
    BOOL _requestingAd;
}
```

.

```
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
if (_requestingAd == NO) {
    _interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
    _interstitial.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"Ad Request");
    _requestingAd = YES;
}

}

-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd                              didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad didFailWithERROR");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    NSLog(@"Ad DidLOAD");
    if (interstitialAd.loaded) {

    CGRect interstitialFrame = self.view.bounds;
    interstitialFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    _adView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:interstitialFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:_adView];

    [_interstitial presentInView:_adView];

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeAd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [_adView addSubview:button];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_adView setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
}

-(void)closeAd:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_adView setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

_adView=nil;
_requestingAd = NO;
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad DidUNLOAD");
}

-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad DidFINISH");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, that tutorial is just a copy of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20858735/2108547) and is extremely dated.

I have a [newer implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32503003/2108547). It's still not perfect though.

Personally, I'd suggest using [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial) or [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/interstitial) for your interstitial advertisements. iAd's interstitials are poorly executed.

Comment: awesome man, I was just looking at your old stack overflow answer when you posted this answer. Thanks dude :)

Comment: I have implemented your new method of the ads however I get an error on every line that references the "release" method. Is there a work around? or do I no longer need these lines?

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Storm gave a good advice.I'd also add that Chartboost and Applovin are good for interstitials. You mentioned that you're using banners (i mean small banners), and i would't recommend them - really disturbing for users. Try interstitials and different types of video, their eCPM is a way higher.You can also make a knight's move using mediation. I stick to Appodeal cause they cover numerous networks effectively and payout on demand.

Comment: @user2876115 " I would also like a way to exit the ad as I believe that the iAds don't come with an exit button, or something similar." - try to use skippable or rewarded videos in your app. The results should be good ;)